# R- filter rows depending on value range across several columns

Tags: r, filter

I have 5 columns with numerical data and I would like to filter for rows that match a data range in at least 3 of the 5 columns.

For example i have the following data frame and I define a value range of 5-10.
My first row has 3 columns with values between 5 and 10, so i want to keep that row.
The second row only has 2 values between 5 and 10, so I want to remove it.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | 10 | 9 | 2 |
| 4 | 8 | 2 | 6 | 2 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `dput` to provide your data set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First test if values in columns are greater or equal 5 and less or equal than 10, then look for rows with 3 or more that fit the condition.

```
dat[ rowSums( dat >= 5 & dat <= 10 ) >= 3, ]
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
1       7       4      10       9       2
```

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(column1 = c(7L, 4L), column2 = c(4L, 8L), column3 = c(10L, 
2L), column4 = c(9L, 6L), column5 = c(2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a second approach:

```
# Setting up data
my_df <- tibble::tibble(A = c(7,4), B = c(4,8), C = c(10, 2), D = c(9,6), E = c(2,2), X = c("some", "character"))
my_min <- 5
my_max <- 10
```

## Then do some tidyverse-magic:

```
# This is verbose, but shows clearly all the steps involved:
my_df_filtered <- my_df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(n_cols_in_range = dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x >= my_min & .x <= my_max)
                ) %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(n_cols_in_range = sum(n_cols_in_range, na.rm = TRUE)
                ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(n_cols_in_range >= 3
                ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-n_cols_in_range)
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
my_df_filtered <- my_df %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::filter(sum(dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x >= my_min & .x <= my_max), na.rm = TRUE) >= 3)
```

But I must state, that the above answer is clearly more elegant since it only needs 1 line of code!